# Service Fabric and IConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to use IConfigurationBuilder for purses of reading xml configuration. However when the service runs (once deployed) it fails at this line:

```
 private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                IConfigurationBuilder Builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); // Exception here
                ..
                ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("MyService.ServiceType",
                        context => new Service(
                            context)
                    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

On the server I see this exception in Application Logs:

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException    at
>   MyService.Program.Main()

If I remove this line it works fine.

And it does WORK fine when I run the service locally from VS.

Comment: is the xml file deployed to the cluster as part of the application package? http://henidak.com/2015/07/blog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the service fabric setting file at run time or to use custom file as setting can use ConfigurationProvider class.  for reference click [here](https://github.com/MikeWasson/ServiceFabric-AspNetCore-Sample).